# Can I use a sprite sheet from an existing video game for my promotional reel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copyright

I want to make a Motion Graphics promotional reel for uploading on YouTube and I like to make something with a retro aesthetic.

I think to use old videogame sprite sheets to make backgrounds and scenarios and I have doubts about legal troubles.

I think copy and paste literally a scenario (i.e, of Megaman X of SNES) could be banned for copyright problems but, what happen if I take the sprites and I reshuffle and remodel them, with transformation and different colours?

For example, the next scenario:

[image]

It's created with Megaman X sprites, but is not a real scenario of Megaman X. Can I use it in the promotional video or I need to transform them or something else?

The video is not focused on earn money, is only for promotion, I want to avoid YouTube deleting it.

Comment: Are you more worried about YouTube algorithms detecting it, or being enough that human lawyers wouldn't send a takedown request in the (unlikely?) case someone happened to point out your video to them?

Comment: Hi Carlos, I took the liberty to copyedit your question a bit for spelling and grammar. If I butchered anything beyond your original intent, feel free to re-edit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is **no such thing** as "change/transform it my X amount and it's okay." That's a *very* common misconception.

If the original copyrighted work can be discerned in **any way**, then at *best* you have *derivative work*, if not a direct *infringement*.

Rearranging a sprite sheet from a copyrighted game is *absolutely* derivative work or an infringement.

And "promotion" **does** constitute a "commercial use" even if it is a loss-leader and not designed to make money directly.

---

Think of it this way...

You purchase a CD of a music album you like.
You decompile the CD (rip the songs to MP3 files)
Then you put the MP3s on a new CD, but in a different order
This is only for promotional purposes, so you can show how good you are at arranging songs, not to make money.

Now, everyone you give your "promo" to can hear how excellent you are at song arrangement. Of course, they also no longer need to go purchase the original album by the artist if they like the music. You may not be *making* money, but you are most certainly costing the copyright holder money.

Have *really* done anything but infringe on the creator's copyright?

---

The truth of the matter is you **can't** create something which is 100% *yours* by using the copyrighted works of others, in part or as a whole, unless *expressed permission* for reuse has been granted (in writing).

Comment: but… but… I sampled it & made a rap record ;))  [If anyone isn't clear on that, I agree with Scott]

Comment: @Tetsujin 100% was waiting for a comment like that `:)`

Comment: Well... I think is not a good idea following my current approach. I mean, I think I could do it and upload it and nothing happens, but the probability of a video ban is there. Someone recommended me to use open license sprite sheets, I guess is a more secure way. Thank you @Scott

Comment: `:)` You can *always* "do it". Just like you *could* go take your neighbor's car without asking.  `:)` Problems only ever arise if you are **caught**. That's true for everywhere, including YouTube.

Comment: @Scott with modern theft protection on automobiles you can't anymore :/ The world used to be more fun

Comment: @Hobbamok allmost certainly you can. You just have to be more determined thats all.

Comment: @Hobbamok Creating a key-fob repeater **IS** kind of fun especially if you're the kind of guy who hang around stackoverflow and stackexchange.